# Error when using DisplayPort monitor - Lenovo X220

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, lenovo

When I connect my Acer 21.5" LCD monitor to my Lenovo X220 using a DisplayPort to VGA connector, the monitor shows up under 'Displays' but when I enable the monitor, it doesn'twork and I get the following message in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
 [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
```

If I connect the monitor using a VGA cable and the VGA port, it works as expected. This laptop has the Intel i5 and HD 3000 graphics chipset. Running 12.04, 3.8.0-35-generic x86_64